# [Java]Why am I getting these errors in my tester class?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a super class, sub class, and a tester class. Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what I need in my tester class- 
1. Create objects of Manager and Employee.

2. Create a function revise salary to revise the salary set in the constructor of Manager or Employee. (Use concept of polymorphism)
3. Use the object’s Display functions to print the relevant information pertaining to the object’s class.

Here are my classes

Superclass:

```
public class Employee {
    private int employeeNumber;
    private String employeeName;
    private double employeeSalary;

    public Employee(int employeeNumber, String employeeName, double employeeSalary) {
         this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
         this.employeeName = employeeName;
         this.employeeSalary = employeeSalary;
    }

         public double getEmployeeSalary() {
            return employeeSalary;
            }

         public void setEmployeeSalary(double employeeSalary) {
            this.employeeSalary = employeeSalary;
            }



         public void display(){
               System.out.println("Employee Number: "+ employeeNumber +"\n"
                     + "Employee Name: " + employeeName + "\n" 
                     + "Employee Salary: "  + employeeSalary);
            }

        }
```

Subclass:

```
public class Manager extends Employee {

    private int rewards;
    public Manager(int employeeNumber, String employeeName, double employeeSalary) {
        super(employeeNumber, employeeName, employeeSalary);
    }


    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println(rewards);
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {


         Manager manager = new Manager(11111, "Elon Musk", 42344);
          manager.display();     

         Employee employeeOne = new Employee(324, "Bob Den", 3522);
         Employee employeeTwo = new Employee(44, "Tim Pipe", 4234 );
         Employee employeeThree = new Employee(42, "Asif Blar", 4321);

         private void reviseSalary() {
         double employeeSalary = manager.getEmployeeSalary();
         manager.setEmployeeSalary(employeeSalary +(employeeSalary /10));
         manager.display();
         }

    }

}
```

**My issue:

I am getting errors on my test class. When I create a manager object, it says the constructor is undefined. Also, for my private void "reviseSalary", it says I cannot use void

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and help in creating my reviseSalary function if possible

Thanks

Comment: could you post the errors you are getting from the console?

Comment: You defined your method 'reviseSalary' within the main method.

Comment: Read what @RobertKock wrote, that's the only problem, everything else is fine.

Comment: @J.Doe You declare and instantiate manager in different method, another method can't access that. You declare it in main and you are trying to access it from reviseSalary().

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your reviseSalary out of main method.

> This error happens because Java does not support nested function.

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {


        Manager manager = new Manager(11111, "Elon Musk", 42344);
        manager.display();

        Employee employeeOne = new Employee(324, "Bob Den", 3522);
        Employee employeeTwo = new Employee(44, "Tim Pipe", 4234 );
        Employee employeeThree = new Employee(42, "Asif Blar", 4321);

        reviseSalary(manager);
    }
    private static void reviseSalary(Manager manager) {
        double employeeSalary = manager.getEmployeeSalary();
        manager.setEmployeeSalary(employeeSalary +(employeeSalary /10));
        manager.display();
    }
}
```

This will be your output:

> - Employee Number: 11111
>
>   - Employee Name: Elon Musk
>   - Employee Salary: 42344.0
> - Employee Number: 11111
>
>   - Employee Name: Elon Musk
>   - Employee Salary: 46578.4

Comment: to call method reviseSalary() the way you show in your example, it should be declared as static. Otherwise, you would need a reference to instance of Test class first to call reviseSalary() on that reference, for example: Test t = new Test(); and then: t.reviseSalary().

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Getting "manager cannot be resolved" error for my manager object inside of the reviseSalary method. any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: @MarcoVeríssimo Getting "manager cannot be resolved" error for my manager object inside of the reviseSalary method. any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: 1) Add an argument to reviseSalary() method declaration: private void reviseSalary(Manager manager) {...}. 2) when you call that method in main() try doing it that way: reviseSalary(manager);

Comment: @J.Doe I test the code and is fully working now. Tell me if you still have a problem

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal thanks, last thing- having a problem calling upon the reviseSalary in the main class. getting "method undefined for type manager" error for " int newSalary = manager.reviseSalary(manager);" ......what am i doing wrong here

Comment: @J.Doe you are using a void method, reviseSalary will not return any int, will just call another methods. Look at my answer.

Comment: @J.Doe if you want to save the final salary in a variable you can do this in the end of your main method `double salary = manager.getEmployeeSalary();`

Answer (score 0):

I see two main problems with your code:

1) You declare method `reviseSalary()` inside `main()` method. Java doesn't allow you to declare method inside of the other method.
You should rather declare it outside of the main() method and add a keyword `static` to let you call this method without the need of having an instance of your `Test` class. Otherwise, if you don't declare this method as `static`, you would need an instance of Test class and have to call `reviseSalary()` on this instance like this:

```
Test t = new Test() ;
t.reviseSalary();
```

2) You declared this field in the `Manager` class: `private int rewards`, but you don't declare any setter method to assign any value to that field.

Comment: @J.Doe If you set this field as static, you are able to set or change value assigned to this field only inside of that class. But in Manager class you provide neither initializing inside the constructor nor setter method to assing a value to that field.